# Silverlight 4 Drag and Drop Treeview

Tags: silverlight, treeview, drag-and-drop, silverlight-4.0

Does anyone have an example for any of the following scenarios.

Given, these are all dynamically populated trees.  Not using a Heirarchal data template, but by iterating through object collections manually and appending children at the appropriate level.

1. Treeview1 has 3 levels, but items can only be reordered within their level.  So, lets say we have Drives, Folders and Files.  Drives can be rearranged in an order, but not put into a Folder.  When navigated down one level in a drive, the individual folders can be reordered, but not dragged between drives.. and same with files, only can be reordered, but not moved to a different folder or drive
2. I have 2 treeviews, Treeview1 is the same as #1 above and Treeview2 is like a picklist of available items.  A user can drag an item from Treeview2 to Treeview1, but it can only be placed at Treeview1's File Level.  The dragged item cannot be a child of a file, or placed at the folder level, nor placed at the drive level.  Also, how to handle the Above, On Top, or Below an item.

I have yet to come across these examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should make 1 ListBoxDragDropTarget with a list box in it. The listbox has 3 item. Each item contains Listbox DragDropTarget with a list box in it. And every sub level contains an listbox again for all the files. With a little effort you can create your own listboxitem which has a button to open or close it like a treeview. And tada,, you can rearrange the items but no the levels.